# when navigating through tab bar elements, navigation controller is not called

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tabBarController with 2 elements: KeyPad, List

The KeyPad- needs to be set only to portrait mode. Inside the UINavigationController - I override the methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

List item starts from a RotationNavigationController - here i ve set all the rotations available.
Everything seems to work ok except of one thing:

- when navigating from List item Bar Controller (which is in Landscape) to KeyPad item bar controller - KeyPad is also in landscape mode. It seems that the 2 methods (shouldAutorotate & supportedInterfaceOrientations) are not called. How to solve this?

I;ve also added the following in viewWillApppear (inside Keypad - which extend a UIViewController)

```
if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
      // Landscape - WHAT TO DO HERE?
      NSLog(@"landscape");
      }
```

**EDIT:**
**Here is what I did for my problem:**

```
//set statusbar to the desired rotation position
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];

//present/dismiss viewcontroller in order to activate rotating.
UIViewController *mVC = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move from one orientation tab to another, it's `shouldAutorotate` is called before anything else. Since you have specified `NO`. It stays at it's previous orientation. I worked around this by `setStatusBarOrientation` in the `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

But I will have to warn you, this changes some things, like if you are checking for orientation anywhere in your code, you will have to check the `statusBarOrientation` instead of the orientation of your `view`/`viewController`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to have a portrait orientation. Why should I set status bar to LandscaoeRight?

Comment: It's a sample code. Just set the orientation as per your choice.

Comment: i ve done it, but no changes in my interface orientation. When I go from second item bar (which is in landscape) to first item bar (which should be in portrait) , the navigation controller is still in landscape mode. If I flip from landscape to portrait the phone, than the navigation controller from first item bar turns into portrat and it remains there no matter how many times i flip from portrait to landscape

Comment: In viewWillAppear I added this:  
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait];

Comment: i ve overriden some methids from NavigationController and now only the StatusBar is in portrait. Everything else remains in landscape mode